# Google Sheet Query function

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

I am just wondering if below code is possible to convert in Google sheet function QUERY(), please see query below:

Query:

SELECT * FROM tblDate WHERE Date IN ('1/1/2000','1/23/2001','3/1/1996','6/23/2022'....etc)

Comment: >= and <= is different from IN functionalities, IN uses a specific dates